# Accessing to generated SSH key with Git bash

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, ssh-keys

I generated a ssh key with git bash. after generating, console showed me:

```
Your identification has been saved in ***
Your public key has been saved in ***.pub
```

after that, when I use `$ls -al ~/.ssh` , it says `//No such file or directory`.

I also tried  `$ ls ~/.ssh/*.sshpub`  and `$ ls -al ~/.ssh #` and got same result

HOW CAN I SEE MY SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

Try generating it again with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

It should generate by default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` / `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`